# Configure yaml in azure devops to run groovy script on Mac

Tags: groovy, azure-devops, yaml, jenkins-pipeline

Earlier I was using JenkinsFile to run CI/CD pipeline in jenkins, but  now we're migrating to Azure DevOps. So to build a pipeline in Azure DevOps on Mac, I'm using a Yaml file.

In jenkinsfile, I ran groovy script using the following syntax:

```
pipe = load ('path/to/groovy/script')
pipe.go()
```

,where "go()" is a function in the groovy script

But, I'm unable to configure the yaml file in similar way

What I found online was running this groovy via gradle build

I want to configure the yaml to run groovy script like in jenkinsfile, as in, without installing gradle or any third party.

Answer (score 0):

> Configure yaml in azure devops to run groovy script

If you are using private agent, you have to install on the agent machine:

- Java 8 JDK
- Apache Groovy 2.5.7 (Downloaded as zip and extracted to some local
  folder)

Then set environment variables, open CMD and run these commands:

```
setx JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101"
setx /M PATH "%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin"
setx GROOVY_HOME "C:\Users\<UserName>\Desktop\apache-groovy-sdk-2.5.7" (the first path is when you extracted the Apache Groovy 2.5.7)
setx /M PATH "%PATH%;C:\Users\<UserName>\Desktop\apache-groovy-sdk-2.5.7\bin" (the first path is when you extracted the Apache Groovy 2.5.7 )
```

Now, we could run groovy scripts without installing gradle or any third party during the building, in the build definition add **Command Line Task** (not Bash) and choose your groovy script:

[image]

If you are using the hosted agent, you need more steps to download and unzip task Apache Groovy 2.5.7.

Hope this helps.

Comment: can you please suggest an edit for agent hosted on mac, and also, I need to confirm if I'll be able to use the same groovy script here as I was using in Jenkins pipeline

Comment: @SaumyaGoyal, Since I am not an expert MAC, to run groovy script on Mac, if possible, you can check if this document can help you:https://pvital.wordpress.com/2018/03/22/installing-groovy-on-mac-os/