# Groovy Script not Running from Azure Pipeline

Tags: groovy, command-line, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Hope someone can help with this trivial task.

I have groovy installed and env variables setup on the build machine to run groovy scripts. If I RDP into the agent and run the script manually, it works, but when I run it from a pipeline using command line task, it seems to find the script but it just sits there with no output or the debug message that I've added to the script.  The build does not fail.  I should be able to atleast see the print statement.

Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

Build Definition:
[image]

Comment: How you running it?

Comment: I added a screenshot of the task definition.  Manually, I type "groovy delta_scan.groovy"

Comment: so why you are not doing the same in your azure command line?

Comment: i mean: tool: `groovy` arguments: `delta_scan.groovy`

Comment: Didn't know I could...all examples I saw only had file name in the Tool field.  This makes more sense.   Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> Groovy Script not Running from Azure Pipeline

To execute the groovy script with command line task in the Azure Devops, we need to confirm where the groovy script file is.

If the groovy script file on the agent machine (local), we need specify the path of the groovy script file, like `C:\Users\user123\Desktop\delta_scan.groovy`:

[image]

That because when we use command line task directly, the **default work folder** for it is:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
```

Obviously, the groovy script file is not in the default path, so we need to provide the full path of the groovy script file.

If you submit groovy script file to the Azure devops repo, we could use [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services) `Build.SourcesDirectory` to get the full path of the groovy script file.

You could check [my another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56901059/configure-yaml-in-azure-devops-to-run-groovy-script-on-mac) for some more details.